# Adding a like box to my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to add a like box from my FB page to my Web Page. I previously had one set up using the code supplied. Since re-modelling the page I can no no longer add the code. I have set up my web page using Made on Mac. It uses an HTML file.